# matomo (piwik), not grouping the similar pages by itself

Tags: matomo

~piwik~ (now matomo), not grouping the similar pages by itself. It groups some of the pages based on the title, but doesn't group most of the pages.

Example:
If I have 3 pages named

```
1. "A Dashboard (ABC awesome)" 
2. "A Dashboard (ABC Good)"
3. "A Dashboard (ABC better)"
```

Then it groups them under a hierarchy like this:

```
+ A Dashboard (ABC
             awesome)
             Good)
             better)
```

Which is perfect.

But in most of the cases, it doesn't group them. For exa, I have 3 pages like this:

```
1. My Area 1234
2. My Area 4567
3. My Area 6789
```

In this case, all above 3 pages, are not grouped. Ideally it should be like this:

```
+My Area
        1234
         4567
         6789
```

But all above pages are shown as a different entries like this:

```
My Area 1234
My Area 4567
My Area 6789
```

I think this is definetely a bug with it, which need to be fixed. I am looking for some workaround or some solution for this.
Please let me know if you need any further information on this.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Matomo only splits on `/`. 
You can find more about this feature here:

https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_62/
and https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/2956

You can set the delimiter in the `config.ini.php` with `action_title_category_delimiter=`

I'm not sure if there is a way to automatically group on similarity and if this wouldn't be quite inconvenient in some cases.

Update 2019:

Starting with Matomo 3.8.0 there is now no default delimiter, so Matomo doesn't do any grouping by default (you can still set the delimiter as explained above)